# How do I override the data type of a model in Swagger/OAS 3?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Let's say I have a model like this:

```
Film:
      properties:
        title:
          type: string
        duration:
          type: string
        actors:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person'
```

And I have a lot of models that inherit from this and add some extra properties.

But I also have a model in which the `actors` are not `Person`s but `Alien`s.

Would I need to remove `actors` from the common model and add it specifically in each inheriting model? (I hope not.)

Can I simply inherit from `Film` and redefine the `actors` attribute?

```
FilmWithAliens:
  allOf:
      - $ref: 'components/schemas/Film'
      - properties:
            actors:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Alien'
```

This seems to work correctly when generating the documentation using Swagger UI. But if I read the Swagger docs here: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/inheritance-and-polymorphism/ 
It seems they say that this is not recommended:

> Note: When validating the data, servers and clients will validate the
>   combined model against each model it consists of. It is recommended to
>   avoid using conflicting properties (like properties that have the same
>   names, but different data types).

So my question is: how should it be done correctly?